# Is there a JAVA sdk for Iot Hub Resource?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I'm looking for CRUD Java APIs for IoT Hub. I'm specifically looking for the java equivalent for this REST API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/iothubresource).

I was able to find APIs to create/register devices and send/receive messages but wasn't able find APIs to CRUD Azure IoT hub.

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure IoT Hub provided different endpoints for manipulate it. These endpoints can be classified as device, service, resource provider, etc(More detail about endpoints of Azure IoT Hub, please refer [Azure IoT Hub endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-endpoints)).

[image]

And Microsoft provide the SDK in different lanuages for Azure IoT hub based on the different endpoints. For example, Microsoft provides C# SDK for Azure IoT Hub for the device and service endpoints named client library(refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/iot/client?view=azure-dotnet)). And Microsoft also provides the C# SDK for the resource provider as [Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/iot/management?view=azure-dotnet).

However there is no JAVA SDK for the resource provider for Azure IoT Hub(refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/iot)). You can use the [REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/iothubresource) in Java for resource provider endpoint of Azure IoT hub. The REST of CRUD Azure IoT Hub, you can refer the links below:

[Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/iothubresource/createorupdate)

[Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/iothubresource/delete)

[Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/iothubresource/get)

In-addition, if you also want Microsoft to provide the Azure IoT resource provider Java SDK, you can vote the feedback from link below:

[Azure IoT Hub management SDK for Java](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot/suggestions/33564925-azure-iot-hub-management-sdk-for-java)